# Rails: JOIN not being created in has_many :through relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Originally, I had two models: "Users" and "Threads". Users had many threads, and threads had one user.

Now, I've added a JOIN called "Publications", and I've adjusted the original "Users" and "Thread" models. However, when I create a new thread, no record is added to the JOIN table (publications), and, the "user_id" column is null in the "Threads" table – there are no errors.

**------------ Update ------------**

I've made a bit of progress – the publication is now being created successfully, and saved with the thread_id. However, the user_id is still null. I've added the controller action below.

Below is my users model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

    devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :confirmable,
           :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

    attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, 
                    :remember_me, :username, :profile_image, 
                    :first_name, :last_name

    has_many :publications
    has_many :threads, :through => :publications

end
```

Below is my publications model:

```
class Publication < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :thread_id, :user_id
  belongs_to :thread
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Below is my threads model:

```
class Thread < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description, :name, :tag_list, :thumbnail_image, :status, :thread_type, :subtitle, :summary

  has_one :publication
  has_one :user, :through => :publication

end
```

Below is the form I'm using to create a new thread – and, when new threads are created, nothing is added to the publications, and, the user_id value for the thread is null in the table:

```
= form_for [@user, @thread] do |f|
  - if @thread.errors.any?
    #error_explanation
      %h2= "#{pluralize(@thread.errors.count, "error")} prohibited this thread from being saved:"
      %ul
        - @thread.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
          %li= msg

  .field
    %span Title:
    = f.text_field :name

  .actions
    = f.submit 'Submit'
```

Below is my controller action:

```
def create
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  @thread = @user.threads.new(params[:thread])
  @thread.build_publication
end
```

Comment: Please edit your question to post the controller action where you are creating the model and relationship.

Comment: I've made a bit of progress – the publication is now being created successfully, and saved with the thread_id. However, the user_id is still null. I've added the controller action below.

Comment: Try `@thread.publication.create` instead of build.

Comment: Thanks @Gene, it looks like build_publication is working properly – now, the only pending issue is that user_id is null when the publication is created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the controller:

```
@user = User.find(params[:id])
@thread = @user.threads.create(params[:thread])
```